# shareArticle only showing domain name on live site, staging is fine - how is LinkedIn processing these differently?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to leverage a Wordpress plugin that does image shares called Share This Image (codecanyon.net/item/share-this-image-image-sharing-plugin/9988272). This plugin utilizes LinkedIn's custom URL sharing tool using "ShareArticle".

The use-case is the visitor visits the page, hovers over the images in the right hand of each "Objective" and clicks one of the social media links. This generates a popup which, for Facebook and LinkedIn is supposed to provide a custom message and image.

It seems to work beautifully on our staging site, but not on the live site - at least not for LinkedIn (Facebook is fine.) The live site only displays the domain name and nothing else when clicking on the LinkedIn share.

I've talked with our hosting provider who made sure we had no caching in place on our end on the live site (staging has no caching by default) but it still doesn't seem to work like our staging site does. I also tried copying our live site to new space (in case there was some oversight in differences between live/staging) and it works just fine. I've also been talking with LinkedIn sales reps we know and they're stumped as well. They suggested posting here.

Given all of this, I'm wondering if there isn't something "stuck" on the LinkedIn side. Perhaps something cached within the bot?

Note that I get the same effect when trying to share the target URL directly in a status update at www.linkedin.com. Without seeing what the LinkedIn bot is seeing, it's difficult to troubleshoot. When I paste the URL that we're passing to LinkedIn I get the proper result in my browser.

Our staging site is: amapatients.staging.wpengine.com

Our live site is: www.patientsbeforepolitics.org

The URLs the plugin is generating for the LinkedIn share (using Objective 2 as the example) are:

Staging LinkedIn window opens with: 
[Staging Site Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIkTS.png)

Live site LinkedIn window opens with: 
[Live Site Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyKaa.png)

Other than paths, the code is basically identical between the sites but the live site is SSL encrypted.

Noting that on some browsers the LinkedIn pop-up just does an endless loading screen that doesn't stop.

I noticed that the times it does work, it only shows the TLD, not the full "www.patientsbeforepolitics.org". The TLD is using domain forwarding through GoDaddy - is that possibly an issue? Are generally 301 redirects problematic?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer at LinkedIn, and I've had a chance to look at this case. Your suspicion about the 301 redirect matches what I am seeing on my side as well.

When I use curl or a web browser to fetch the url, the live site responds with a 301 redirect, like this:

```
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Thu, 23 Mar 2017 15:04:16 GMT
< Location: https://www.patientsbeforepolitics.org/wp-content/plugins/Share-This-Image/sharer.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.patientsbeforepolitics.org%2F%2315535&img=www.patientsbeforepolitics.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Objective1.jpg&title=AMA%20Patients%20Before%20Politics%20Obj%201&desc=Ensure%20current%20levels%20of%20coverage%20%20coverageaccess%20for%20uninsured&netwoe
```

However, when our server fetches the url, we identify ourselves using a different LinkedInBot user-agent string.

And the response that we get to our request is different:

```
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Thu, 23 Mar 2017 15:00:17 GMT
< Location: http://www.patientsbeforepolitics.org/wp-content/plugins/Share-This-Image/sharer.php
```

All the parameters have been stripped off the redirect location, so that when we then try to follow the redirect, we hit a dead end, and we don't get the data we need to create the correct share on LinkedIn.

So, this 301 redirect that returns a different location for our LinkedInBot user-agent seems to be the reason why your live site is giving you different results from your staging site, which doesn't have a redirect. If you are able to configure your site to handle our user-agent the same as a web browser, sharing on your live site should work too.

I hope this helps.